# Clear unordered map before running parallel creation of adjacent list - OpenMP C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, unordered-map

I'm trying to make a benchmark that measures the time taken to create the adjacent list of a graph, given its list of edges using OpenMP with different number of threads.

In order to do so I have to free the previous adjacent list to be reloaded using a different number of threads. However the point is that all the four lines of code that I have commented at the beginning of the function thrown the following exception: `An exception was thrown: read access violation. _Val was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.` These three are the three strategies that I've tried.

Moreover, removing the cleaning step, everything works fine except that I end up increasing the number of adjacent vertices every time by the same vertices.

```cpp
template<typename EdgeList, typename AdjacentList>
inline void UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>::GetAdjacentList(const int num_threads)
{
    // ALL OPTIONS THROWN THE SAME EXCEPTION
    //1- this->adjacent_list.clear();
    //2- AdjacentList(this->n_vertices).swap(this->adjacent_list);
    //3- this->adjacent_list = AdjacentList(this->n_vertices);
    //4- AdjacentList temp = AdjacentList(this->n_vertices);
    //   this->adjacent_list.swap(temp);

    if (num_threads > 1) {
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i = 0; i < this->n_vertices; ++i)
            omp_init_lock(&this->writelock[i]);
    }
    
    auto start = now();

    #pragma omp parallel for if(num_threads > 1) num_threads(num_threads)
    for (int i = 0; i < this->n_edges; i++) {

        int v1 = this->edge_list[i].first;
        int v2 = this->edge_list[i].second;

        if (num_threads > 1) omp_set_lock(&this->writelock[v1]);
        auto it1 = upper_bound(this->adjacent_list[v1].begin(), this->adjacent_list[v1].end(), v2);
        this->adjacent_list[v1].insert(it1, v2);
        if (num_threads > 1) omp_unset_lock(&this->writelock[v1]);

        
        if (num_threads > 1) omp_set_lock(&this->writelock[v2]);
        auto it2 = upper_bound(this->adjacent_list[v2].begin(), this->adjacent_list[v2].end(), v1);
        this->adjacent_list[v2].insert(it2, v1);
        if (num_threads > 1) omp_unset_lock(&this->writelock[v2]);

    }

    auto end = now();

    if (num_threads > 1) {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < this->n_vertices; ++i)
            omp_destroy_lock(&this->writelock[i]);
    }

    this->elp_adj[num_threads - 1] = (end - start);

    this->density = static_cast<double>((2 * this->n_edges) / (this->n_vertices * (this->n_vertices - 1)));
    
}
```

**Edit**

This is the class UndirectedGraph that contain all the information.

```cpp
template<typename EdgeList, typename AdjacentList>
class UndirectedGraph {
private:
    string name = "";
    int n_edges = 0;
    int n_vertices = 0;
    double density = .0;
    unordered_map<int, Duration> elp_adj;
    vector<omp_lock_t> writelock;


public:
    EdgeList edge_list;
    AdjacentList adjacent_list;

    void printProprieties();
    void TriangleCounter(const int num_threads); // not implemented
    void GetResultByThread(int thread);
    void WriteResultsCsv(string results_path);
    void GetAdjacentList(const int num_threads);

    UndirectedGraph() { }

    UndirectedGraph(filesystem::directory_entry entry) {
        if (entry.is_regular_file()) {

            vector<string> row;
            string line, word;
            vector<int> temp_vertices;

            this->name = entry.path().generic_string();
            this->name.erase(this->name.begin(), this->name.begin() + 11);

            cout << "Reading file: " << this->name << " ...";

            ifstream file(entry.path(), ios::in);

            // Reading the edges file

            if (file.is_open()) {
                while (getline(file, line)) {
                    int first, second;

                    row.clear();

                    stringstream str(line);

                    while (getline(str, word, ','))
                        row.push_back(word);
                    this->n_edges += 1;

                    first = stoi(row[0]);
                    second = stoi(row[1]);

                    this->edge_list.push_back(make_pair(first, second));

                    if (find(temp_vertices.begin(), temp_vertices.end(), first) == temp_vertices.end()) temp_vertices.push_back(first);
                    if (find(temp_vertices.begin(), temp_vertices.end(), second) == temp_vertices.end()) temp_vertices.push_back(second);

                }
            }
            file.close();

            this->n_vertices = static_cast<int>(temp_vertices.size());
            this->writelock = vector<omp_lock_t>(this->n_vertices);

            cout << "  DONE\n";
        }
    }
};



template<typename EdgeList, typename AdjacentList>
inline void UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>::printProprieties()
{
    cout << "Name: " << this->name << " - Number of Edges: " << this->n_edges << " - Number of vertices: " << this->n_vertices << endl << endl;
}





template<typename EdgeList, typename AdjacentList>
inline void UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>::GetAdjacentList(const int num_threads)
{

    // ----------------- ALL THROWN AN EXCEPTION -----------------
    //1- this->adjacent_list.clear();
    //2- AdjacentList(this->n_vertices).swap(this->adjacent_list);
    //3- this->adjacent_list = AdjacentList(this->n_vertices);
    //4- AdjacentList temp = AdjacentList(this->n_vertices);
    //   this->adjacent_list.swap(temp);;

    if (num_threads > 1) {
    #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < this->n_vertices; ++i)
            omp_init_lock(&this->writelock[i]);
    }

    auto start = now();

    #pragma omp parallel for if(num_threads > 1) num_threads(num_threads)
    for (int i = 0; i < this->n_edges; i++) {

        int v1 = this->edge_list[i].first;
        int v2 = this->edge_list[i].second;

        if (num_threads > 1) omp_set_lock(&this->writelock[v1]);
        auto it1 = upper_bound(this->adjacent_list[v1].begin(), this->adjacent_list[v1].end(), v2);
        this->adjacent_list[v1].insert(it1, v2);
        if (num_threads > 1) omp_unset_lock(&this->writelock[v1]);


        if (num_threads > 1) omp_set_lock(&this->writelock[v2]);
        auto it2 = upper_bound(this->adjacent_list[v2].begin(), this->adjacent_list[v2].end(), v1);
        this->adjacent_list[v2].insert(it2, v1);
        if (num_threads > 1) omp_unset_lock(&this->writelock[v2]);

    }

    auto end = now();

    if (num_threads > 1) {
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < this->n_vertices; ++i)
            omp_destroy_lock(&this->writelock[i]);
    }

    this->elp_adj[num_threads - 1] = (end - start);

    this->density = static_cast<double>((2 * this->n_edges) / (this->n_vertices * (this->n_vertices - 1)));

}


vector<UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>> ReadFromDirectory(string path) {
    vector<UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>> graphs_list;

    for (const auto& entry : filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
        graphs_list.push_back(UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>(entry));

    return graphs_list;

}
```

The main file is composed by

```cpp
string ReturnResultPath() {

    stringstream results_path;

    /*time_t curtime;
    time(&curtime);
    string ts = string(ctime(&curtime));*/

    time_t result = time(NULL);
    char timestamp[26];
    ctime_s(timestamp, sizeof timestamp, &result);
    string ts = string(timestamp);

    ts.erase(remove(ts.begin(), ts.end(), '\n'), ts.cend());

    replace(ts.begin(), ts.end(), ' ', '_');
    replace(ts.begin(), ts.end(), ':', '.');

    results_path << "./results/results_" << ts << ".csv";
    return results_path.str();
}

void RunTriangleCounter(vector<UndirectedGraph<EdgeList, AdjacentList>> graphs_vector, string results_path) {
    for (auto& graph : graphs_vector) {
        cout << "\n";
        graph.printProprieties();

        cout << "Number of available cores: " << thread::hardware_concurrency() << "\n\n";

        for (int threads = 0; threads < MAX_THREADS; threads++) { // untill 20 threads

            if (threads == 0)
                cout << "SEQUENTIAL EXECUTION ...\n";
            else 
                cout << "PARALLEL EXECUTION WITH " << threads + 1 << " THREADS ...\n";
            graph.GetAdjacentList(threads + 1);
            graph.TriangleCounter(threads + 1); // not implemented
            graph.GetResultByThread(threads);
        }

        cout << "\n\n";
    }
}


int main() {
    string standford_datasets_path = "./datasets/standford";
    string results_path = ReturnResultPath();

    RunTriangleCounter(ReadFromDirectory(standford_datasets_path), results_path);
    return 0;
}
```

The includes are the following one:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mutex>
```

For better explaination I link the github repository [github repository](https://github.com/zuliani99/Graph_Triangle_Counter)

Comment: What are AdjacentList clear and swap methods? Why AdjacentList(this->n_vertices).swap(this->adjacent_list) and not  this->adjacent_list.swap(AdjacentList(this->n_vertices))?

Comment: AdjacentList clear is a method of the unordered_map that free the data structure. Swap just swap the content of two unordered maps. Well your suggestion does not complie, moreover I tryed to use AdjacentList(this->n_vertices).swap(this->adjacent_list) since is suggested in the vector.clear() reference (https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) page and thus i though was applieable also here

Comment: Why is the clear step needed? In the 3rd commented line you assign a new `AdjacentList` object, so the previous object should be automatically destrructed. The 2nd commented line is equally a mystery. It looks like you swap the current list (which was cleared in the 1st line) into a new object that then is never used again. Are you using global data?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Why do you use `this` pointer? I see no reason to use e.g. `this->n_vertices` instead of the much simpler `n_vertices`.

Comment: The commented lines are the three options that I’ve tried and all of three thrown the same exception. Regarding the `this`, I simply like using it, since it dosen't make any difference from using it and not.

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing more details about your class, we are unable to help you.

Comment: I've included the vast majority of the application code

Comment: @zulle99 I think providing the implementation of the class used as `AdjacencyList` would help. At least its data members and its `clear()` function.

Comment: Done, my mistake I forgot to incude that part. However `AdjacencyList` is nothing else than an `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>`

Comment: @zulle99 Calling `clear()` on an `unordered_map` should never be a problem. There's something bigger at play. One cause of "simple function failing spectacularly with errors mentioning memory" is when an object is in a bad state or has been heap-allocated but not correctly initialized or when you use a reference to an object that's already been destroyed. Stuff like that. Unfortunately, nothing stands out from the rest of your code that would indicate that to me. At this point, I'd suggest stepping through with a debugger and inspecting the data closely as you're about to call `clear()`.

Comment: @screwnut Thanks for the suggestion, furthermore it is strange that sometimes the computation stops at the x and other time at thread y. I mean...I though that the problem was in the critical section part of the openmp for loop, but after double checking it, it feels correct. And as proof, removing the clear process makes tha application runs fine. And personally I do not know where look since the only parts that I write the adjecant_list is the examined function, everywhere else I only read. In any case I'll act as you suggested!

Comment: Regarding the function `GetAdjacentList` are you sure that is corrent and i'll not encounter any case of race condition / deadlock? Moreover I've tried to return the adjacent_list as a return value from the same function and in this case i get `Expression: vector emplace iterator outside range`, and one of the stack calls points to one of the upper_boud in the parallel for